# Wordpress 2014 child theme setup

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am having trouble activating  a child theme for a wordpress 2014 theme.
I created a folder twentyfourteen-child. I have a style.css with

```
1 /*  
2 Theme Name:Twenty Fourteen Child
3 Version: 1.0
4 Theme URI: link
5 Description: A basic starter child theme for Twenty Fourteen 
6 Author: Tim 
7 Author URI: link
8 Template: twentyfourteen
9 License: GPL 
10 License URI: ...
11 */
```

And a functions.php with

```
 1<?php
 2 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
 3 function enqueue_parent_styles() {
 4         wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style',  get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
 5 }
```

I am running another wordpress site with the same theme and the same code, which is working fine. The two websites are both installed in subdirectories
and the Template name from the style.css is matching the directory name of the parent theme. I basically just copied these two files.

When i activate the child theme the menu structure is destroyed. The side contains a menu on the left side and the top side, but now they are both merged in the top menu. Has someone an idea what could be wrong here!?

Comment: Are you making a child theme of the `twentyfourteen` theme? Or a different theme?

Comment: I created a child theme for the twentyfourteen theme

Comment: Did you make a **functions.php** or a **function.php** (notice the 'S')

Comment: The file name is functions.php

Comment: I edited your question to fix the "function.php" filename.

Comment: I tried to change the name but it did not work. Also i read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) that the file name is functions.php

Comment: Check what you are getting in get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: How can i check the return value of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already set up your theme and you activate your Child Theme after that, you have to reassign your menu's true Appearance -> Menu's.

Comment: The menu structure is not changed. The partitioning is untouched. But the themes gets also back to its default color (green) and the header image disapeared

Comment: You need to redo you customizations if you switched to a child theme. Go to Themes -> Customize and retry customizing. Normally you start with a Child theme beforehand, not after you done some work already :)

Comment: OK. I thought i created a child theme for the other site after i did some things, maybe my memory tricked me. :) Was actually not too much hustle to redo the setting in the dashboards.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious solution